# SocketIO IO.socket(uri) function always throws a URISyntaxException (Java)

Tags: java, socket.io

I'm trying to set up SocketIO in my Java Android application. Here's my Socket managing class. Note that the SERVER_URL is not actually 0.0.0.0 on my file but rather a real IP address that other programs are able to access:

```
public class SocketManager {

    private static final String TAG = "SocketManager";
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://0.0.0.0:8081";

    private static Socket socket;

    private SocketManager() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "URISyntaxException");
        }
    }

    public static Socket getInstance() {
        if (socket == null) {
            new SocketManager();
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

The issue is that, no matter what I seem to do, the URISyntaxException always gets thrown. What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

I am using SocketIO version 2.0.0.

I have tried manipulating the URL in several ways - using https rather than http, removing the http://, etc.

I have also tried to Google about this issue but it seems no one has posted about it before, so here I am.